# Click on a photo for showing information

Tags: html, css

Is it possible when clicking on a photo, you can let an screen pop up with some information, instead of using a hover or a href?

It is for showing some extra information about the people shown on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try opening up an overlay or other modals to show the information you need; try something like this, **clicking** on the image will bring up an overlay with some text:

```js
document.querySelector('#image').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('show')
}

document.querySelector('.overlay').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('show')
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="image" id="image" />
<div class="overlay">
  <p>
    Your content would go here
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. It is only possible to do this with the help of Javascript (and these scripts often need some info on what to display)

There is no "best" plugin for this, so if you search for "lightbox javascript" you will find many solutions, some jquery Plugins and some standalone solutions. Use one script that suits your needs, nearly every script can be adapted in how it looks, they mostly differ from the implementation method or in the way they behave/their features.

You can also try to use the [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element from HTML5 but this also requires Javascript for correct setup. It is also not fully supported in every browser